# Splitting a line in gnuplot based on a column

Tags: linux, plot, gnuplot

I have a bunch of data like this:

```
0 0 50.5 -3.39358e-05
0 0 150.5 5.11472e-06
0 0 250.5 -3.87604e-06
0 0 350.5 -2.54219e-05
0 0 450.5 3.92257e-06
0 0 550.5 0.00198317
0 0 650.5 -4.96953e-05
0 0 750.5 -3.60458e-05
0 0 850.5 -2.30878e-05
0 0 950.5 1.67545e-07
1 0 126.5 4.17028e-05
1 0 226.5 -1.43637e-05
1 0 326.5 1.42918e-06
1 0 426.5 1.18147e-05
1 0 526.5 0.0020478
1 0 626.5 1.58651e-06
1 0 726.5 3.18537e-05
1 0 826.5 2.47536e-05
1 0 926.5 -4.20655e-05
```

I want to plot something like this on gnuplot:

```
plot file using 3:($4+$1*factor) with lines
```

But this gives me one continuous line for all the data. I want one line for each unique value of `$1`. ie., one continuous line for all data where `$1=0`, then another line for `$1=1` and so on. How can I add such a discontinuity in the line?

Comment: If your data all have the same structure and the lines of `$1=0` and `$1=1` are the same, you can use `every` keyword in the `plot` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an external tool to preprocess your data to add an empty line whenever the value in the first column changes (doesn't work on Windows):

```
plot '< awk ''{if(x!=$1) {print ""}; x=$1;print}'' test.dat' using 3:($4 + $1*factor)
```

The empty line in the data file prevents gnuplot from connecting the separated data points.

Comment: I kind of get what you did there with the awk, but can you tell me how gnuplot interprets it?

Comment: The `<` tells gnuplot to get the data from what the following shell expression writes to standard output.