# Is it possible to use row number instead of spaces to create a 2d heat map type plot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to create heatmap 2 as described here: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/heatmaps.html

But this requires there to be blank spaces inbetween the data, whereas my data looks like this:

`0 0 5
0 1 4
0 2 3
0 3 1
0 4 0
1 0 2
1 1 2
1 2 0
1 3 0
1 4 1
2 0 0
2 1 0
2 2 0
2 3 1
2 4 0
3 0 0
3 1 0
3 2 0
3 3 2
3 4 3
4 0 0
4 1 1
4 2 2
4 3 4
4 4 3`

Is there a way to get gnuplot to use the number of entries as an indicator instead of the blank line i.e. to get to the 5th row 1 4 1 and then start a new line?

Any tips? Thank you

Comment: Gnuplot itself cannot do this, but you can use e.g. `awk` to do this processing for you. The expression in http://stackoverflow.com/a/27634411/2604213 should work exactly for your case.

Comment: Thank you. I am using windows for gnuplot but I am getting my data from linux, the command would be newtest.dat<awk ''{if(x!=$1) {print ""}; x=$1;print}'' test.dat for changing the file?

Comment: Almost. To change the file, use `awk '{if(x!=$1) {print ""}; x=$1;print}' test.dat > newtest.dat`. The doubled single quotes are only gnuplot's way of escaping them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and you want the first two columns (or any other columns you specify) determine the structure of the map/data, then newlines aren’t required anymore.

At least with Gnuplot 4.6 and Gnuplot 5.0, plotting your data with

```
plot "data.dat" with image
```

yields no different result than plotting it with newlines inserted after every fifth line.